# Suspend-to-RAM with systemd configuration

Tags: systemd, power-management, suspend

I want to [Suspend-to-RAM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html#suspend-to-ram)
 with `systemd`.

[The Linux kernel user's and administrator's guide says](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html#basic-sysfs-interfaces-for-system-suspend-and-hibernation):

> [T]here is only one way to make the system go into the suspend-to-RAM state (write `deep` into `/sys/power/mem_sleep` and `mem` into `/sys/power/state`).

How do I "Suspend-to-RAM" (rather than plain "[Suspend](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html#standby)") using `systemd`?

Answer (score 4):

#### `mem_sleep` modes are not supported via `systemd`

[`systemd-sleep.conf(5)`](https://manned.org/systemd-sleep.conf.5) only mentions `/sys/power/disk` and `/sys/power/state` but not `/sys/power/mem_sleep`.

[Searching the code for `mem_sleep`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/search?q=mem_sleep) returns nothing.

I raised the feature request: [Support suspend modes "s2idle", "shallow", and "deep" #13451](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13451)

---

#### Workaround

Use the [kernel command line `mem_sleep_default=deep`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html):

> ```
>    mem_sleep_default=      [SUSPEND] Default system suspend mode:
>                     s2idle  - Suspend-To-Idle
>                     shallow - Power-On Suspend or equivalent (if supported)
>                     deep    - Suspend-To-RAM or equivalent (if supported)
>                     See Documentation/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.rst.
> ```

[HTML rendering of `Documentation/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.rst`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html)